# Stripe too many high risk payments

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm using the stripe subscription API to provide multi tier accounts for my users. but about 50% of the transactions that i get in stripe are declined and flagged as fraudulent. how can i diagnose this issue knowing that i'm using the default base code provided in the stripe documentation (front end) and using the stripe python module (backend).

I know that i haven't provided much information, but that is only because there isn't much to provide. the code is known to anyone who has used stripe before, and there isn't any issue with it as there are transaction that work normally.

Thank you !

Comment: If you suspect the problem to be outside of the code, then I suspect the question to be outside of topics accepted on SO. We can't help you with the fraud detection of a 3rd party.

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com) as this is more a question of their systems than any code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting stripe support, i found that many payments were done by people from an IP address that belongs to a certain location with a card that is registered to a different location.

for example if someone uses a French debit card from England. i did ask stripe to look into this issue.